# AI Files Not Opening Since New Update

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6, creative-cloud

I am currently working with another graphic designer.

- She Keeps encountering AI files not opening when selecting them from her specific project folder such as opening with the "right click open with"
  option.
- She is using windows 7 at the moment at work and has to open up illustrator and select the file drop down in Illustrator to open up that specific AI File.
- I strictly use creative cloud with my mac and have not encountered this issue since the new creative cloud roll out.
- I have had her uninstall and reinstall AI and the same issue keeps occurring

Any suggestions would be great

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

First test would be to try the same process on a different windows computer. My guess is something is wrong in the windows system that the request to open is not getting to the application.

What happens when the designer does the right click method? Does illustrator open? Come to the front but not do anything?